# Js RegExp: выбор текста между тегами

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Нужно написать скрипт который будет искать текст между  тегами `<script></script>`, я не силён в регулярных выражениях, но попробовал написать выражение.

```
<script>(.*?)</script>
```

Но это не работает. Как сделать это правильно?

Comment: `/<script[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/`

Comment: @genson, http://vk.cc/1fjDBd Пробую отладить не получается, в чём причина не подскажите?

Comment: В исходниках prototype есть такая штука /<script[^>]*>([\\S\\s]*?)<\/script\\s*>/ мне кажется она как раз для этого

Comment: Так? http://goo.gl/XdkPL

Comment: @reinraus, да спасибо всё работает.

Comment: @ReinRaus: (наша с вами любимая тема)

1. `<script><![CDATA[ var s = "</script>"; ]]>  </script>`
2. `<script.disabled> var x = 0; <script.disabled> <script> var x = 1; </script>`
3. `<!-- <script> --> <script> var x = 1; </script>`

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/189364/c-вырезать-текст-между-тегами-регуляркой

Comment: @VladD, в JavaScript расширенный вариант нельзя решить регулярным выражением ввиду отсутствия рекурсии в движке.  
Мой излюбленный ответ на нашу любимую тему :)  
> у меня есть нож (RegExp) и есть хлеб (текст который надо разобрать, подчиненный некой системе и структуре), зачем мне точить нож до такой остроты, чтобы я им мог разрезать орех (сферический текст в вакууме), если ореха у меня нет и не будет ?

Comment: Отсутсвтие рекурсии в движке JavaScript??? Это неверно. И это можно легко показать на примере...

Comment: @heavy_metal_fan имеется ввиду движок регексов, мы же про них говорим.

Comment: @ReinRaus: вот вам парсер HTML на регулярках от [Тома Кристиансена](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Christiansen): http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/276994. Мой излюбленный ответ на ваш ответ:

> нет смысла выпускать ружьё, из которой можно застрелить только воробья-самца, только если он летит вам навстречу, не чирикает, при отсутствии ветра и других птиц в радиусе километра.

А насчёт сферического теста в вакууме -- в моих примерах валидный HTML.

Comment: @ReinRaus: А вообще, выбор за ТС. Если он может на 100% гарантировать, что HTML, который он хочет распарсить, будет иметь жёсткую структуру, и поставить безопасность своего приложения в зависимость от этого -- тогда пусть делает как ему проще.

Comment: @VladD, как показательный пример что лучше не делать этого регулярными выражениями тот ответ хорош, но он на самом деле не совсем корретно парсит HTML, а значит нам не подходит.  
Например тот код не отработает  

    <tagname attribute="text \" text " >

---------------

@VladD И вправду. Почитал RFC на HTML- нельзя так делать. Узнал, что даже в  

    <tagname attribute="text > text " >
парсер имеет полное право принять **>** внутри аттрибута как конец тэга.

--------------------

и чат бы и вправду не помешал :)

Comment: @ReinRaus: у вас вроде не валидный HTML: нужно [применять `&quot;`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4015380/276994). Если я правильно понял, парсер Кристиансена написан так, чтобы игнорировать неправильные значения.

Comment: @ReinRaus: вы бы опубликовали свой код как ответ.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Надо бы попросить на Мета либо чат, как на SO, либо поднять лимит комментариев. Либо хоть форум.

Comment: @ReinRaus: вы меня [опередили](http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/845/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Необходимо подобрать регулярное выражение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1433115/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2):

Задача поставлена путано: автор просит «написать скрипт», но из дальнейшего текста вопроса следует, что необходимо обычное регулярное выражение. Также не очень понятно, нужна ли именно реализация регулярного выражения на JavaScript или же метка [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) проставлена по ошибке, только потому что операция поиска производится в содержимом скрипта.

Если формулировка следующая: «найти текст между тегами `<script></script>` с помощью регулярных выражений», то приведу шаблон для PCRE. Т. к. атрибут *type* в HTML5 [можно опустить](https://webref.ru/html/script#field_html_note), в ответе он не учитывается.

*Регулярное выражение:*

```
(?<=<[Ss][Cc][Rr][Ii][Pp][Tt]>)([\s\S]*?)(?=<\/[Ss][Cc][Rr][Ii][Pp][Tt]>)
```

*Демонстрация:*

https://regex101.com/r/oO7pR0/1

*Пояснения:*

Используются метасимволы поиска контекста, они могут поддерживаться не везде:

- `?=` — положительный просмотр вперёд,
- `?<=` — положительный просмотр назад.

[Выражение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521328/199934) ув-мого Гены Царинного находит текст вместе с тегами, а автору, насколько понял, сами теги не нужны. Нахождение содержимого внутри них — случай применения «операций нулевой ширины» с приведёнными выше метасимволами.

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

```
/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/
```

Comment: [**Ваш пример**](https://regex101.com/r/kB1jK6/2). **[1]** Автору, насколько я понял, необходимо выражение, ищущее текст только **между** тегами, но не вместе с ними. // **[2]** Не учтены заглавные буквы. [**Мой пример**](https://regex101.com/r/kB1jK6/4). // **[3]** Не свои ответы здесь принято помечать как общие. // Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, поправлю

Comment: @СашаЧерных, по содержимому ответа, лучше привести свой собственный вариант.

Comment: Cheops, хорошо, я свой ответ напишу.