# Извлечение содержимого атрибута href

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет, помогите написать регулярное выражение, для получения кода из href-атрибута

```
href="watch?v= тут код"
```

из огромной строки html контента.

Comment: html лучше разбирать функциями http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php  А так в общем то `/от(.*?)до/`

Comment: Есть [**программа**](http://www.sobolsoft.com/extractlinkhtml/), извлекающая значения атрибутов *href* и/или *src*.

Comment: Потестировал программу, она извлекает якоря и содержимое относительных путей. К тому же платная. Если нужно извлечь только ссылки, составляющие значения атрибутов *href* или *src*, шаблон такой: `(?<=[href|src]=")https?:\/\/.*?(?=")`. [**Демонстрация**](https://regex101.com/r/sR8bB0/1).

Comment: Парсить HTML регулярками нельзя. _Ваш К.О._

Answer (score 3):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$html = 'href="watch?v= тут код"';
preg_match('/href="watch\?v=([^"]+)"/', $html, $out);
echo $out[1];
```

Comment: cheops, почему в Вашем примере необязательно защищать `+` знаком `?` ? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, дело в том, что мы используем символ [^"]+ - произвольное количество символов, за исключением двойных кавычек, благодаря этому мы не можем выбраться за первую же ". Если бы мы использовали .+, тогда да нужно было изменять жадность при помощи .+?. Иногда бывает, что неизвестно заранее используется одинарная или двойная кавычка, в этом случае можно использовать выражение вида /href=["']watch\?v=([^"']+)["']/

Comment: Привыкший всегда защищать жадные кванторы, не понял сразу эту особенность. Благодарю.

Comment: cпасибо, всё работает ;)

Comment: @Artur, разве? Вы не [**так**](https://regex101.com/r/jE5mD5/1) хотели?

Comment: Да всё верно так. А возможно искать ещё в блоке id="result" это выражение?

Comment: я обычно это делаю с помощью symfony crawler , но с youtube контент толи защищён толи что у них блок есть body-early в нём frame с html doctype и crawler то что за ним больше ничего не видит

Comment: @Artur, не совсем Вас понял. 

> А возможно искать ещё в блоке id="result" это выражение? —

Уточните, пожалуйста, что Вы хотите найти.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39498/discussion-between---and-art-ur).

Comment: у меня контент есть который я спарсил по ключевому поиску с youtube, и я хочу получить код от первого видео из списка. Этот список находится в блоке id="result" в href="href="watch?v=

Comment: @Artur, всё равно не доходит до меня( . Напишите, пожалуйста, так же понятно, как в вопросе: `href="watch?v= тут код"` — как выглядит кусок кода, и где в нём находится тот текст, который Вы хотите извлечь.

Comment: @Artur, пожалуйста, в начале сообщений добавляйте `@Саша Черных`, чтобы мне поступали уведомления о Ваших комментариях.

Comment: @Саша Черных, попробую с другой стороны подойти. Возможно ли обрезать html контент который находится в строке? другими словами много html кода у меня есть а я хочу с него вытащить содержимое которое в <div id="results"></div>?

Comment: @Artur, [**так**](https://regex101.com/r/jE5mD5/2)? [**Здесь**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521348/199934) в ответе на аналогичный вопрос я расписал подробности.

Comment: @Саша Черных, как эта ваша регулярка, только она почему-то не всё содержимое того что в нём берёт в чём может быть причина? (?<=<div id="results">)([\s\S]*?)(?=<\/div>  вот набросал контент [ссылка](https://regex101.com/r/jE5mD5/3)

Answer (score 1):

вот что я делаю:

```
    $youtubeUri = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_type=videos&search_query=".$filmsInfo[$key]['title'];
    $request = $this->client->request('GET', $youtubeUri);
   $content = $request->getBody()->getContents(); // Тут весь контент есть с ним всё хорошо.
```

Обычно далее я использую symfony crawler

```
$crawler = new Crawler($content)->filter('#results')->html();
```

Но в моем случаи у youtube я не знаю для чего есть блок early-body в котором iframe с каким-то Doctype и crawler видим только его контент другой не видит

Comment: @Саша Черных, задача у меня получить код для трайлера фильма который выйдет. Название у меня есть, по названию трейлер чаще всего первый в списке видео. )