# Необходимо подобрать регулярное выражение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

**Доброго времени суток, не разу не сталкивался с регулярными выражениями. Сейчас необходимо вытащить подстроку с помощью регулярного выражения.**

**Строка**:
`Привет мир, как дела? Сегодня прекрасно. [data]Подстрока с информацией[/data]`

**Буду рад развернутому ответу.
Заранее спасибо.**

Comment: В целом тут можно и без регулярки (если одно вхождение). Если в строке много таких шаблонов будет - то да, можно регуляркой

Comment: Какая есть идея?

Comment: Вначале ответь, в строке будет только один шаблон `[data] string [/data]` или может быть несколько.

Comment: Только один шаблон, как вы указали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так например, если несколько таких штук:

```js
const regexp = /\[data\](.*?)\[\/data\]/gi;

const string = 'Привет мир, как дела? Сегодня прекрасно. [data]Подстрока asdasd с информацией[/data] Привет мир, как дела? Сегодня прекрасно. [data]Подстрока sdс нужнёй информацией[/data]';

const datas = Array.from(string.matchAll(regexp), x => x[1]);

console.log(datas);
```

Если же всего 1 раз такое встречается, то можно так:

```js
const regexp = /\[data\](.*)\[\/data\]/gi;

const string = 'Привет мир, как дела? Сегодня прекрасно. [data]Подстрока asdasd с информацией[/data] Привет мир, как дела? Сегодня прекрасно';

const data = [...string.matchAll(regexp)][0][1];

console.log(data);
```

А ещё можно с помощью `split` так:

```js
const string = 'Привет мир, как дела? Сегодня прекрасно. [data]Подстрока asdasd с информацией 1[/data][data]Подстрока asdasd с информацией 2[/data] Привет мир, как дела? Сегодня прекрасно [data]Подстрока asdasd с информацией 3[/data]';

const data = string.split(/\[\/?data\]/).filter((x, i) => i % 2);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: @balabaev00 немного изменил ответ, упростил регулярные выражения

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!

Comment: @balabaev00 Добавил ещё один метод регулярками. Не забудьте пожалуйста отметить один из ответов Принятым, поставив зелёную галочку слева от ответа, если ответ вам помог

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов:

1. Найти с помощью **[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)**  позицию вхождения двух тегов
2. С помощью **[substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)** взять подстроку от начала первого тега + 6 сиволов (т.к. в `[data]` их столько) до начала второго тега

---

Ещё вариант без регулярки в один проход цикла. На счёт скорости конкатенации не могу подсказать.

```js
let str = 'Привет мир, как дела? Сегодня прекрасно. [data]Подстрока с информацией[/data]';

let getSubstrbetweenTags = (str) => {
  let result = '';
  let closeBracketFound = false;
  
  for (let char of str) {
      if (closeBracketFound && char === '[')
          closeBracketFound = false;

      if (closeBracketFound)
          result += char;

      if (char === ']')
          closeBracketFound = true;    
  }
  
  return result;
}



console.log(getSubstrbetweenTags(str));
```

Comment: Да, как вариант рабочий, но выглядит немного костыльно.

Comment: Чем это костыльно?

Comment: А ты знаешь, что регулярки работают долго и нагружают CPU?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Уже который раз встречаю "регулярки работают долго", можешь пожалуйста дать источник откуда эта инфа? Я просто не могу понять, насколько они долго работают, что лучше применять 2 раза поиск по строке и потом брать подстроку, чем 1 регулярное выражение. Или это подразумевается, что регулярка плохо работает, если не аккуратно написан? Просто на практике не сталкивался с тем, что приходилось бы переписывать регулярку на несколько методов, потому что регулярка работает долго или тормозит комп

Comment: @EzioMercer  Источники вряд ли найду.... максимум от пыхи сравнения https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9hSu.png  и https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fjdH.png  .... сам я недавно тоже с этим столкнулся и в замерах на тестах увидел явное замедление на регулярках.....кстати, это одна из причин, почему Jquery пло[ по сравнению с современным JS, т.к. в жквери всё на регулярках....... но инфу проще самому поискать............. да, от одной простой регулярки тормозить не будет ничего, но в целом даже в этом решении простом, может быть замедление (незначительное)

Comment: Офигеть, разница прям до 10х доходит иногда... Да я искал сам, просто каждый своё пишет, не наткнулся на объективные тесты в JS, а свои писать не охота было. За картинки отдельное спасибо :)

Comment: @EzioMercer вообще за один проход цикла думаю быстрее и регулярок и вызова функций будет работать))) `let result = '';
for (let char of str) {
    if (closeBracketFound && char === '[')
        closeBracketFound = false;
    
    if (closeBracketFound)
        result += char;
    
    if (char === ']')
        closeBracketFound = true;    
}

console.log(result);`  ахахах.... хотя как там скорость конкатенации хз

Comment: Ну зачем в комментарии, мы же тут ругаем за такое? На счёт скорости конкатенации, не думаю что это занимает хоть какое-то значительное время, особенно, если добавлять в конец. Вот если добавлять в начало, тогда каждый символ приходилось бы переиндексировать, а так думаю не медленне чем в массив положить что-то. Если тут строки устроены +- как в C, то строка - просто массив символов, так что думаю 1 проход это самый быстрый вариант :)

Comment: Кстати зря как по мне ты пропукскаешь проверку `data`. Если будет `[такая информация]`, то ты её пропустишь)

Comment: Действительно, работает реально гораздо дольше, проверил. Спасибо большое за оперативный ответ!

Comment: Кстати провёл тут небольшой тест и оказалось, что действительно регулярки медленнее чем несколько методов подряд применённых. В строке было 111014 сиволов и вот [результаты](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyDBJ.png)

Comment: @EzioMercer "Кстати зря как по мн" ---- ну да, решение не без нюансов ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   но тут уж зависит от того, что там реально будет. Решать это уже разраобтчику